# Union types Array of objects and numbers, problem with looping trough it

Tags: typescript

In the following code I think I'm correctly checking the type before logging but I still get squiggly lines.
[image]

I've tried also checking for typeof "object" instead but i get the same result.
Any idea why?

Comment: share the tsplayground link or share the code

Comment: Playground : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJwJ7OQbwFDAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANx4ID2ANk1KQM5hSgDmDAL55GTEN2SFMnUgAp0GAD4Ua0AJQBtALrbkAXmQa82DQAYANBZxFiARnPJmbDgHIoEQi8Fbzxw9ZIAJgcndmIXaigmAHcQL3MA4gBmENYwlwwIFjZo+MSAFlTncOoWRABrLx8-DUSAViL06IALYEg8mwA2Rtd3T0FLLTwhvBh2WRYIMGRgPVM6GYAefIXgAGo1tVw-MagJqeQAKzmFw+XTja38bGw-bGAYZFkwDAAHCCZHqQxODWAdQ5afR6AwuJjUQ4QBBgFxXO6OMScVgQAB0bD4sm+v3+GkBKNCUDUfkEyCynBQ1xuzHEyLRTAxWL+AK0ROwwnZeCAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate it out into a variable so, typescript knows you are dealing with the same value.

```js
for(let i=0; i<4; i++) {
  for(let j=0; j<4; j++) {
    const item = days[i][j]
    if (typeof item === 'object') {
    console.log(item.color)
  } else {
    console.log(item)
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is TypeScript needs to know you are narrowing the same variable, so you need to assign the value to a variable before you do the type narrowing using `typeof`.

```
interface Day {
  id: number;
  color: string;
}

const days: (Day | number)[][] = [
  [0, 0, { id: 1, color: 'red' }],
  [{ id: 2, color: 'brown' }, { id: 3, color: 'yellow' }, { id: 4, color: 'black' }],
  [{ id: 5, color: 'white' }, { id: 6, color: 'red' }, 0]
]

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    const d = days[i][j];
    if (typeof d === 'object') {
      console.log(d.color)
    } else {
      console.log(d)
    }
  }
}
```